# nav-tabs Not Scrolling with overflow-x: scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to use `nav-tabs` from Bootstrap 4, and when it has too many items, I wanted to make it scrollable.

First, the default behavior is moving items to next line. I fixed this with `white-space: nowrap` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

And I realized that the container is expanding along x axis even there's an disabled scrollbar. I tried to fix it with giving `max-width: 100%`, but it's not working. I found that using specific px value makes it work, but it's not a good solution for me.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link active">Active Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `display:block!important;` to `.nav` **instead** `display:flex`

```css
.nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:block!important;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link active">Active Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link active">Active Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link active">Active Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item px-1">
    <a class="nav-link">Tab</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution (and making all wrapper tags `w-100`) solved the problem.

Comment: In my case the bootstrap li were floated, so those needed a float: none as well